# Unificar todas las impresiones que mando en un VBA en un documento para imprimir conjuntamente

Tags: vba

Tengo este código y me gustaría lanzar todas las impresiones en un solo documento para así poder imprimir a doble cara en la impresora, ya que actualmente las lanza de una en una y no tengo esa opción, además de que haya un campo que se autoincremente según las copias que mande

Al final lo que yo quiero es lo siguiente,

1º paso --> Solicite el "Identificador"
2º paso --> Solicite el "N de impresiones"

Si "Identificador" = 1996 y "N de impresiones" = 6 --> Me mande 6 impresiones con el identificador incrementando hasta 2002 y que se haga en Doble cara.

Muchas gracias!

---

```vb
Sub TOP()

    Dim sInput As String

    sInput = InputBox("Garantía de calidad COPIA Nº", "Getting my doc prop val")
    ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties("Counter").Value = sInput
    
            Dim i As Long, j As Long
        With ActiveDocument
          j = CLng(InputBox("Número de impresiones", "Print Copies"))
          For i = 1 To j
        With .CustomDocumentProperties("Counter")
          .Value = .Value + 1
        End With
         .Fields.Update
            ActiveDocument.PrintOut Copies:=1
        Next
           .Save
        End With
            

End Sub
```

Comment: Entiendo que:
- El documento es de una sola página
- Imprimes copias del mismo
- Y quieres que la impresión de dichas copias se imprima en Duplex
Confirma y te doy una solución.

Comment: Eso es el documento es una captura de pantalla y encima un Campo que se auto incrementa según las copias que mande, y lo que quiero es que se impriman en duplex eso es, si mando imprimir 4 copias por ejemplo quiero que se impriman 2 hojas por las dos caras. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Para forzar la impresión del documento a duplex:

```
Sub TOP()

Dim sInput As String

sInput = InputBox("Garantía de calidad COPIA Nº", "Getting my doc prop val")
ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties("Counter").Value = sInput

 Dim i As Long, j As Long
    With ActiveDocument
        j = CLng(InputBox("Número de impresiones", "Print Copies")) * 2
        
            With .CustomDocumentProperties("Counter")
              .Value = .Value + 1
            End With
             .Fields.Update
                ActiveDocument.PrintOut Copies:=j
             .Save
    End With
```

End Sub

Como ves, he quitado el For/next, ya que lo único que necesitas para forzar la impresión a duplex es indicar que el numero de copias es j
(la impresora por defecto tendria que tener impresión duplex habilitada)
El inputbox ahora solicita el número de impresiones/hoja y lo multiplica por 2 para forzar la impresión duplex.
Ahora bien, no sé lo importante que sería el "counter" ni si lo necesitas después de estos cambios...Quita las lineas del counter, ya que ahora, según entiendo su función, no sería necesario. Y el campo de word tampoco sería necesario.
Quedando así:

```
Sub TOP()
Dim sInput As String
Dim j As Long
    With ActiveDocument
        j = CLng(InputBox("Número de impresiones", "Print Copies")) * 2
        ActiveDocument.PrintOut Copies:=j
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Buenas @pcandido muchas gracias de antemano

Al final lo que yo quiero es lo siguiente,

En el paso 1.(SERIAL) Me pida el numero que va a plasmar en el documento (Lo tenemos)
En el paso 2.(NUMERO DE IMPRESIONES) Me pida la cantidad de impresiones que va a realizar con las condiciones siguientes:

 Si 1.(SERIAL) = 2000 y le indico que 2.(NUMERO DE IMPRESIONES) = 20 
 Lo que yo quiero es que me imprima 20 copias incrementando el 1.(SERIAL) hasta terminar en 2020 y que todo esto lo haga en doble cara asi que serían 10 folios.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda, espero haberme aclarado mejor

Comment: He modificado la entrada para aclararme mejor discúlpame

Comment: Ok, siendo así, hay que tener en cuenta más cosas:
-¿Sería posible que el documento tuviera siempre 2 páginas? Dado que son idénticas
Eso facilitaría el tema del counter

Comment: ¿Dicho de otro manera. Ese documento ya existe, solo tienes que acceder al él cuando es necesario? Por que se ser así, la solución es más sencilla

Comment: El documento existe, se compone de una imagen + el counter el cual quiero que incremente según las impresiones que le mande , la imagen siempre es la misma. Y todo esto mandarlo a un documento que lo imprima a doble cara